# How to access Apple Id "Sign In" dialog from UI Test?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, xctestcase

I have some UI tests and wanna test what happens when I press "subscribe" button. In simulator there is an alert displayed asking to sign in with apple id:

[image]

I tried to wait for alert using `app.alerts["Sign In"]` predicate and using `addUIInterruptionMonitor` function. No luck. I even tried to wait for "Cancel" button to appear, this also didn't work.

Any ideas how to handle this alert and press "Cancel"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with this alert is that it is not being created from your app, but from the system app - **Springboard**. So, to be able to query elements from that app, you have to create `XCUIApplication` object with the Springboard bundle ID:

```
let springboardApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
```

Then, find your alert with:

```
let signInAlert = springboardApp.alerts.element
```

You should then be able to find the *Cancel* button:

```
signInAlert.buttons["Cancel"].tap()
```